# Docker graceful shutdown on VM stop with GCE/Docker

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'd like to shutdown my docker app when the GCE VM stops.

I use a docker image on GCE:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY dist/fetcher.js ./

CMD [ "node", "fetcher.js" ]
```

fetcher.js is:

```js
console.log('## start');

setInterval(() => console.log('tick'), 10 * 1000);

for (const signal of ['SIGTERM', 'SIGINT', 'SIGHUP']) {
  process.on(signal, async (signal) => {
    console.info(`Got ${signal}. Graceful shutdown start at ${Date().toString()}`);
    process.exit();
  });
}
```

Locally I can see the log message when using `docker kill -s 1 <container>`:

```
## start
tick
tick
tick
Got SIGHUP. Graceful shutdown start at Mon Jan 03 2022 04:39:53 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

It works well when I SSH into the VM and run the same command (`docker kill -s 1 <container>`).

However I can not see the log when I stop the VM:

```
tick
...
tick
methodName: "v1.compute.instances.stop"
```

For some reason the signal handler does not seem to be executed.

I have tried different things:

- with and without tini,
- writing a file to google storage in the signal handle (in case the problem is the log).

But none of this works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must use a shutdown script instead of trying to catch signals that are not sent. The Google Compute Engine shutdown is an ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) event that triggers a script. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript

Comment: I am using the config to run a container (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers). That is I have no startup script to start my container but it is taken care of by GCE. I thought that in this case shutdown would also be handled automatically. I'll try to create a script to stop docker and report.

Comment: Are you using Compute Engine Container Optimized OS (COS)? In that case, the container shutdown is managed for you. I am not sure how to interject your own scripts to replace that without building your own setup. COS is locked down to changes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @John Hanley and would like to add that [Stopping an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) causes Compute Engine to send the [ACPI Power Off signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) to the instance and therefore I believe it is an intended behavior that log processing will be stopped when the shutdown or stopping signal is sent for a GCE VM. Getting the logs from the GCE VM, once the stop signal is processed, is fairly impossible. This could be the reason why you were not receiving further logs.

Comment: I have also tried to write a file to Google Storage on top of the file (See "writing a file to google storage in the signal handle (in case the problem is the log)." in my original post.
This does not work either - it is not included in my simplified code.
I'll keep trying and report what I find.